# Raku parallel/functional methods

Tags: raku

I am pretty new to Raku and I have a questions to functional methods, in particular with reduce.
I originally had the method:

```
sub standardab{
  my $mittel = mittel(@_);
  my $foo = 0;
  for @_ {
    $foo += ($_ - $mittel)**2;
  }
  $foo = sqrt($foo/(@_.elems));
}
```

and it worked fine. Then I started to use reduce:

```
sub standardab{
    my $mittel = mittel(@_);
    my $foo = 0;
    $foo = @_.reduce({$^a + ($^b-$mittel)**2});
    $foo = sqrt($foo/(@_.elems));
}
```

my execution time doubled (I am applying this to roughly 1000 elements) and the solution differed by 0.004 (i guess rounding error).
If I am using

```
.race.reduce(...)
```

my execution time is 4 times higher than with the original sequential code.
Can someone tell me the reason for this?
I thought about parallelism initialization time, but - as I said - i am applying this to 1000 elements and if i change other for loops in my code to reduce it gets even slower!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I calculated the execution time with:
say now - INIT now;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Summary

- In general, `reduce` and `for` do different things, and they are doing different things in your code. For example, compared with your `for` code, your `reduce` code involves twice as many arguments being passed and is doing one less iteration. I think that's likely at the root of the `0.004` difference.
- Even if your `for` and `reduce` code did the same thing, an optimized version of such `reduce` code would never be faster than an equally optimized version of equivalent `for` code.
- I thought that `race` didn't automatically parallelize `reduce` due to `reduce`'s nature. (Though I see per your and @user0721090601's comment I'm wrong.) But it *will* incur overhead -- currently *a lot*.
- You *could* use `race` to parallelize your `for` loop instead, if it's slightly rewritten. That *might* speed it up.

## On the difference between your `for` and `reduce` code

Here's the difference I meant:

```
say do for    <a b c d>  { $^a }       # (a b c d)      (4 iterations)

say do reduce <a b c d>: { $^a, $^b }  # (((a b) c) d)  (3 iterations)
```

For more details of their operation, see their respective doc ([`for`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/for), [`reduce`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/reduce)).

You haven't shared your data, but I will presume that the `for` and/or `reduce` computations involve `Num`s (floats). Addition of floats isn't commutative, so you may well get (typically small) discrepancies if the additions end up happening in a different order.

I presume that explains the `0.004` difference.

## On your sequential `reduce` being 2X slower than your `for`

> my execution time doubled (I am applying this to roughly 1000 elements)

First, your `reduce` code is different, as explained above. There are general abstract differences (eg taking two arguments per call instead of your `for` block's one) and perhaps your specific data leads to fundamental numeric computation differences (perhaps your `for` loop computation is primarily integer or float math while your `reduce` is primarily rational?). That *might* explain the execution time difference, or some of it.

Another part of it may be the difference between, on the one hand, a `reduce`, which will by default compile into calls of a closure, with call overhead, and two arguments per call, and temporary memory storing intermediate results, and, on the other, a `for` which will by default compile into direct iteration, with the `{...}` being just inlined code rather than a call of a closure. (That said, it's possible a `reduce` will sometimes compile to inlined code; and it may even already be that way for your code.)

More generally, Rakudo optimization effort is still in its relatively early days. Most of it has been generic, speeding up all code. Where effort has been applied to particular constructs, the most widely used constructs have gotten the attention so far, and `for` is widely used and `reduce` less so. So some or all the difference may just be that `reduce` is poorly optimized.

## On `reduce` with `race`

> my execution time [for `.race.reduce(...)`] is 4 times higher than with the original sequential code

I didn't think `reduce` would be *automatically* parallelizable with `race`. Per [its doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/reduce), `reduce` works by "iteratively applying a function which knows how to combine two values", and one argument in each iteration is the result of the previous iteration. So it seemed to me it must be done sequentially.

(I see in the comments that I'm misunderstanding what could be done by a compiler with a reduction. Perhaps this is if it's a commutative operation?)

In summary, your code is incurring `race`ing's overhead without gaining any benefit.

## On `race` in general

Let's say you're using some operation that *is* parallelizable with `race`.

First, as you noted, `race` incurs overhead. There'll be an initialization and teardown cost, at least some of which is paid repeatedly for each evaluation of an overall statement/expression that's being `race`d.

Second, at least for now, `race` means use of threads running on CPU cores. For some payloads that can yield a useful benefit despite any initialization and teardown costs. But it will, at best, be a speed up equal to the number of cores.

(One day it should be possible for compiler implementors to spot that a `race`d `for` loop is simple enough to be run on a GPU rather than a CPU, and go ahead and send it to a GPU to achieve a spectacular speed up.)

Third, if you literally write `.race.foo...` you'll get *default* settings for some tunable aspects of the racing. The defaults are almost certainly not optimal and may be way off.

The currently tunable settings are `:batch` and `:degree`. See [their doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/hyper#Options_degree_and_batch) for more details.

More generally, whether parallelization speeds up code depends on the details of a specific use case such as the data and hardware in use.

## On using `race` with `for`

If you rewrite your code a bit you can `race` your `for`:

```
$foo = sum do race for @_ { ($_ - $mittel)**2 }
```

To apply tuning you must repeat the `race` as a method, for example:

```
$foo = sum do race for @_.race(:degree(8)) { ($_ - $mittel)**2 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much this explains a lot. I'm just used to some other programming languages and also some functional ones. E.g. reduce (the seem to be scala equivalent of folding) is indeed highly parallelizeable, but you are probably right - it may not be implemented in raku yet

Comment: While reduce is supposed to be sequential, it could theoretically optimize, and that could be a neat little adverb, `:communative`.  Then ^1_000_000_000.reduce(*.sum) could be split into 8 groups of 12_500_000 ops, run parallel, and then have their results added together.  I know some of the `[ ]` metaops are internally optimized already

Comment: raiph: I posted as a comment only because I don't think it's really an answer to the OPs' question.  (slash thinking it might be a cool module or core addition)

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf It sounds like you're saying Scala knows when a reduction is parallelizable, eg (or ie?) if the operation being reduced is commutative, and, with a large enough list, automatically parallelizes it, presumably as outlined by .@user0721090601. Is that about right?

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf I *think* (hope!) I'm at the end of rewriting my answer! I apologize if you've been reading interim versions as I try to get it right(er).

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf I now presume the numeric difference between your `for` and `reduce` solutions is due to float addition not being commutative; and you perhaps relying on commutativity to ignore the difference between the N iteration `for` solution and the `N-1` iteration `reduce` one; and the actual calculations involved for your data leading to use of floats that, on addition in a different order, yield the `0.004` difference.

Comment: I just didn't know that reduce starts with the first two arguments (I thought It'd start with 0 or something). As I already said I am used to Scala which has fold. There are different folding types: foldLeft (a reduce from left to right), foldRight and fold. The last one does not specify a folding order, so you have to write the function for this folding technique commutatively - so this one is parallizable. Also you can specify a start value. So it's quite different than Rakus reduce - I just hadn't known that yet

Comment: And thank you for your extensive answer. It answers my question perfectly and gave a good insight into Raku and optimization in Raku :)

Comment: @Sprinklerkopf Ahhh. That all makes sense. For other readers, in Raku, per the doc, if the reducing operation is not an arbitrary routine but instead an operator, then "its inherent identity value and associativity is respected " so that "With a right-associative operator it is a right fold" and "otherwise (and usually) it is a left fold". Also, "you may want to prefix the input list with an explicit identity value" so, eg. `(indentity-value, |@rest).reduce... `.